# Border matrix with multiple indices on top and bottom

Tags: tables, matrices, arrays

How can I write a matrix where there is an index at the top and also at the bottom? `\bordermatrix` doesn't seem to have an option for multiple indices.

Comment: Look for the package `blkarray`; there are examples on this site.

Comment: @ashpool The young package `nicematrix` does a very good job very easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example using the [`blkarray`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 \\
\begin{block}{(ccccc)c}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{block}
d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & d_4 & d_5 \\
\end{blockarray}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A `TikZ` based solution! By means of the comment **percusse** suggested, it is possible to make the `foreach` loop simpler: it iterates on rows/columns of the names that `matrix of math nodes` gives to each entry of the matrix and reuses that number also in the border index.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
P&=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),inner sep=4pt,ampersand replacement=\&]
{
x_1 \&  y_1 \& s_1 \&  z_1 \\
x_2 \&  y_2 \& s_2 \&  z_2 \\
x_3 \&  y_3 \& s_3 \&  z_3 \\
x_4 \&  y_4 \& s_4 \&  z_4 \\
};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\foreach \s in {1,2,...,4}{
% bottom index
\node[red,shift=(m-4-\s.south),yshift=-0.4cm](0,0) {$a_{\s}$};
}
\foreach \n in {1,2,...,4}{
% top index
\node[blue,shift=(m-1-\n.north),yshift=0.4cm](0,0) {$b_{\n}$} ;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Following the strategy, it is also possible to define indices on the matrix's left or right side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
P&=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),inner sep=4pt,ampersand replacement=\&]
{
x_1 \&  y_1 \& s_1 \&  z_1 \\
x_2 \&  y_2 \& s_2 \&  z_2 \\
x_3 \&  y_3 \& s_3 \&  z_3 \\
x_4 \&  y_4 \& s_4 \&  z_4 \\
};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\foreach \s in {1,2,...,4}{
% bottom index
\node[blue,shift=(m-4-\s.south),yshift=-0.4cm,text height=1ex,](0,0) {$a_{\s}$};
}
\foreach \n in {1,2,...,4}{
% right index
\node[green!70!blue,shift=(m-\n-4.west),xshift=1.5cm,text height=1ex,](0,0) {$b_{\n}$} ;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: You can simplify the foreach loop via `\node[blue,shift=(m-1-\n.north),yshift=0.4cm](0,0) {$b_{\n}$};`. You also don't need align here.

Comment: Thanks for the nice suggestion: it's really smart ;). The align is just a remain of a previous answer, but I kept because maybe the OP needs to insert this matrix inside an math environment.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c}
\textcolor{blue}{ \begin{array} {c@{\hspace{13pt}}c@{\hspace{13pt}}c@{\hspace{13pt}}c@{\hspace{13pt}}c@{\hspace{13pt}}c@{\hspace{-10pt}}}
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 & y_5 & y_6    
\end{array}}\\[5pt]
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\\ x_4 \\ x_5
\end{matrix}\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
0.9 &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0 \\
1  & 0.4 & 0.5 &  0  &  0  &  0 \\
0  &  0  &  1  &  0  &  0  &  0 \\
0  &  0  & 0.2 &  1  &  0  &  0 \\
0  &  0  &  0  & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the last code edited by percusse, output is not matching with the code. I am also interested in the code that matches the output. Someone, please help me!

Comment: Maybe below answer helps.

Comment: Edited and amended.

Answer (score 2):

The package `nicematrix` provides tools to do such things easily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-row = \color{red},
                   code-for-first-col = \color{blue},
                   code-for-last-row = \color{green},
                   code-for-last-col = \color{magenta}}
$\begin{pNiceArray}{cc|cc}[first-row,last-row=5,first-col,last-col,nullify-dots]
       & C_1    & \Cdots &        & C_4    &        \\
L_1    & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & L_1    \\
\Vdots & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & \Vdots \\
\hline
       & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} &        \\
L_4    & a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} & L_4    \\
       & C_1    & \Cdots &        & C_4    &     
\end{pNiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{align*} P=\begin{array}{c} \textcolor{blue}{ \begin{array}{c@{\hspace{13pt}}c@{\hspace{13pt}}c@{\hspace{13pt}}c@{\hspace{13pt}}c@{\hspace{13pt}}c}
    y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 & y_5 & y_6     \end{array}}\\[5pt] \begin{array}{c} a\\b\\c\\d\\e \end{array} \begin{bmatrix}
    0.9 &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0 \\
    1  & 0.4 & 0.5 &  0  &  0  &  0 \\
    0  &  0  &  1  &  0  &  0  &  0 \\
    0  &  0  & 0.2 &  1  &  0  &  0 \\
    0  &  0  &  0  & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.2
    \end{bmatrix}   \end{array} \end{align*}
```